# How to find Bretta?

Tags: hollow-knight

How can I get to Bretta in Hollow Knight? I can't seem to find a secret passage to get to her.

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you have the air dash, double jump and wall climb abilities. The double jump is optional but makes things much easier.
- Go to the very bottom right room of the Fungal Wastes, where there is an entrance to the Royal Waterways. Do not enter the waterways.
- Look at the map. There is an icon at the bottom of the room you are in. It shows a small statue. Go to the statue. This is where the Dashmaster Charm can be found if you haven't picked it up already.
- Walk through the wall to the left of the statue. If you can't walk through it directly, try attacking it first.
- Go as far left as you can in the room you just uncovered and climb the wall up as high as you can. There is a hole in the roof that you can get into with some tricky jumping and dashing. If you have the double jump, this is much easier.
- Follow the linear path after this. There will be a lot of spikes to avoid.
- Bretta is sitting at the end.